# MySQl query issues for adding data to table 1 from table 2 and 3 with a join

Tags: java, mysql, sql, foreign-keys, inner-join

I have a problem with a query in MySQL and I have looked so many places for an answer.
What I want is to insert data into Table1 column 2 and 3 with data from table 2 and 3 column 2 and 2.

I have the following tables.

```
Table1 (products):
Column1 = productId (Autoincrementing int)
Column2 = fkCategory (int, Foreign key pointing to the categoryId)
Column3 = fkBrand (int, Foreign key pointing to the brandId)

Table2 (categories):
Column1 = categoryId (autoincrementing int)
Column2 = category (Varchar)

Table3 (brands):
Column1 = brandId (Autoincrementing int)
Column2 = brand (Varchar)
```

When I make the following query everything goes right and it inserts a row with data in column 1 (autoincremented key) and column 2 (the data I wanted) in table 1, but nothing in column 3 of course:

```
INSERT INTO products (fkCategory)
Select categories.categoryId
FROM categories
WHERE category = 'Bluser';
```

Now I want to add a value to column 2 and column 3 of the same row in table 1 inside the same query with data from table 2 and 3 and I try to make the following query. This one gives me the message: unknown column 'products.fkBrand'

```
INSERT INTO products (fkCategory, fkBrand)
Select categories.categoryId, brands.brandId
FROM categories
INNER JOIN brands ON brands.brandId = products.fkBrand
WHERE category = 'Bluser' and brand = 'Ganni';
```

I also tried the following query:

```
INSERT INTO products (fkCategory, fkBrand)
Select categories.categoryId, brands.brandId
FROM products
INNER JOIN categories ON categories.categoryId = products.fkCategory
INNER JOIN brands ON brands.brandId = products.fkBrand
WHERE category = 'Bluser' and brand = 'Ganni';
```

This one gives me no complications when running it, but does not add any values to table1.

I am kinda lost and I guess my problem is in the Where clause or in the way I am joining it. I have tried tons of other queries, but I did not want to add too much code to the question thread.

Any help is much appreciated :). Nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't join on table product since before the insert the table is empty and it results in an empty set. The following query performs a cross join of tables 2 and 3 producing the result set you want to insert into product :

```
INSERT INTO products (fkCategory, fkBrand)
Select c.categoryId, b.brandId
FROM categories c,brands b
WHERE c.category = 'Bluser' and b.brand = 'Ganni';
```

Comment: Great. It worked perfectly. Thank you :).. I actually had the idea that I could not make a FROM clause with multiple tables in it, but there you go. No need for the join then.